# How to add more than one currency to the Woocomerce Currency Filter

Tags: php, arrays, woocommerce, wordpress

I know very little PHP and I'm sure this is something pretty simple, but I'm stuck :-( .
Woocommerce have a currency filter that can be used to add more currencies. This is how the code they provide in [their documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/add-a-custom-currency-symbol/) looks:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currencies', 'add_my_currency' );

function add_my_currency( $currencies ) {
 $currencies['ABC'] = __( 'Currency name', 'woocommerce' );
 return $currencies;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'add_my_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function add_my_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
 switch( $currency ) {
      case 'ABC': $currency_symbol = '$'; break;
 }
 return $currency_symbol;
}
```

How can I have that add more than one currency? (In my mind it should be something like)

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_currencies', 'add_my_currency' );

function add_my_currency( $currencies ) {
 $currencies['ABC'] = __( 'Currency name', 'woocommerce' );
 $currencies['DEF'] = __( 'Currency name 2', 'woocommerce' );
 return $currencies;
}

add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'add_my_currency_symbol', 10, 2);

function add_my_currency_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
 switch( $currency ) {
      case 'ABC': $currency_symbol = 'ABC'; break;
      case 'DEF': $currency_symbol = 'DEF'; break;
 }
 return $currency_symbol;
```

Comment: I just did an 'internet search' of your question title and this turned up. I have no idea whether it will help or not: Somewhere to start? [Multi-currency support for WooCommerce : Works on WooCommerce 2.1 and above...](http://wpml.org/documentation/related-projects/woocommerce-multilingual/multi-currency-support-woocommerce/) I had a look - it seems 'sensible' but only you will know if it helps.

Comment: @RyanVincent I had seen that. What it refers to is configuring settings to show the already existing multi-currency feature on the front-end. What I seek is to be able to add new currencies.

Answer (score 0):

Figured this out. All I needed to do was change the second paramenter of the filter and the corresponding function name like so:

```
// Woocommerce add Malawi Kwacha (MK)

add_filter( 'woocommerce_currencies', 'add_mk' );  
function add_mk( $currencies ) {
  if(!isset($currencies['MK'])||!isset($currencies['MK'])){
 $currencies['MK'] = __( 'Malawi Kwacha', 'woocommerce' );
 return $currencies;
 }
}
add_filter('woocommerce_currency_symbol', 'add_mk_symbol', 10, 2);
function add_mk_symbol( $currency_symbol, $currency ) {
switch( $currency ) {
  case 'MK': $currency_symbol = 'K'; break;
}
return $currency_symbol;
}
```